# cvPtr2D equivalent in c++ OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use some code that uses older OpenCV (C), CvMat... but in a context of c++

I can't find the equivalent of cvPtr2D.

going from

```
void some_function (const CvMat * src, CvMat * dst)
{
..
double * w = (double *) cvPtr2D(dst, dst->rows - 1, 0);
..
}
```

to

```
void some_function (const cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst)
{
 ????
}
```

I have tried things like

double * w = (double *) cv::Ptr(dst, dst->rows - 1, 0);

or something similar ? I get compile errors, and I can't even figure out if Ptr does the same thing...

What is the equivalent in c++ OpenCV for cvPtr2D ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenCV's C++ interface, lots of functions became member functions, so I think you are looking for

```
void some_function (const cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst)
{
  ..
  int row_idx = dst.rows-1;
  int col_idx = 0;
  double * w = src.ptr<double>(row_idx)+col_idx;
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
void some_function(const cv::Mat & src, cv::Mat & dst )
{
..
    double * w = &dst.at<double>( dst->rows-1, 0 );
..
}
```